# Is comparing the strings of pre-order traversal of 2 trees with null nodes sufficient and necessary to determine if a tree is a subtree of another?

Tags: binary-tree, tree-traversal, preorder

I have 2 binary trees, and the value of nodes are not necessary distinct. I want to determine if one tree is a subtree of another.

Is comparing the strings of the pre-order traversal of 2 trees **with null nodes** sufficient and necessary (iff condition) to determine if a tree is a subtree of another?

For example,

A.left = B

Pre-order: A, B, null, null, null

A.right = B

Pre-order: A, null, B, null, null

Comment: No.  Consider the tree `A -> B -> C`.  It's a subtree of `A -> B -> C`, but not of `A <- C -> B`, even though they have the same preorder traversal.

Comment: Even simpler: `A.left = B` and `A.right = B`. This smells like homework. Don't forget to give credit to SO in order to avoid violating your school's academic honesty policy.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth: Doesn't the P.O.T. of A->B->C start with A, but the P.O.T. of A<-C->B start with C?

Comment: @ScottHunter: Ah, yes.  So I meant `B <- A -> C`!

Comment: Why not search for the root of the first tree in the second one, then do a direct tree comparison? That would be faster than generating a full preorder just to do a substring search. Also much easier for the next person to maintain the code to understand.

Comment: Ok, the null nodes possibly makes a difference (but I don't know off-hand).  Either way, the question reduces to "is this representation enough to uniquely reconstruct the original tree?"